# gcc -save-temps: how to specify directory

Tags: gcc

Is it possible to specify the output directory of the [`-save-temps`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options) artifacts?

I know I can do a `mv` afterwards but wondering if there's a way to avoid the extra step.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify that the `-save-temps`
artifacts will be saved in current directory of the compilation with either of:-

```
-save-temps
-save-temps=cwd
```

Or you can specify that they will be saved in the same directory as the corresponding `.o` files,
provided that the `-o` option is also used, with:

```
-save-temps=obj
```

Those are your only options. Here is [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options)

Comment: Oh, *thank you*. Do you know when they introduced `-save-temps=obj`? I had some temporaries overwriting each other in my make process with the first one, and I didn't see the other option.

Comment: @DanielH. `-save-temps=obj` was introduced in GCC 4.5

Comment: Then I must have somehow just missed its existence, but does mean I can use it now.