# Building kernel with `-save-temps`

Tags: linux, makefile, build, preprocessor

I'm building the Linux Kernel with the gcc options `-save-temps` in order to see exactly how all the C files get preprocessed. I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483572/building-kernel-with-save-temps-are-these-9-mb-of-i-files-all-that-there-is/71838181#71838181),

but I got the following error message, the message is too long, so I chose some below

```
core.s:286501: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15557' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15557' {*UND* section}

core.s:286515: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15559' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15559' {*UND* section}

core.s:286552: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15565' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15565' {*UND* section}

core.s:286710: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15580' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15580' {*UND* section}

core.s:286779: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15589' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15589' {*UND* section}

core.s:286801: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15592' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15592' {*UND* section}

core.s:286819: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15595' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15595' {*UND* section}

core.s:286928: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15614' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15614' {*UND* section}

core.s:287030: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15663' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15663' {*UND* section}

core.s:287235: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15723' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15723' {*UND* section}

core.s:287240: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15731' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15731' {*UND* section}

core.s:287244: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15733' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15733' {*UND* section}

core.s:287343: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6441' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6441' {*UND* section}

core.s:287370: Error: can't resolve `.LBE15824' {*UND* section} - `.LBB15824' {*UND* section}

core.s:287387: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6460' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6460' {*UND* section}

core.s:287431: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6199' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6199' {*UND* section}

core.s:287583: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6220' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6220' {*UND* section}

core.s:287688: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19308' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19308' {*UND* section}

core.s:287709: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19312' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19312' {*UND* section}

core.s:287786: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19339' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19339' {*UND* section}

core.s:287860: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19357' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19357' {*UND* section}

core.s:288065: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19421' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19421' {*UND* section}

core.s:288070: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19429' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19429' {*UND* section}

core.s:288074: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19431' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19431' {*UND* section}

core.s:288109: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6221' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6221' {*UND* section}

core.s:288196: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19583' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19583' {*UND* section}

core.s:288265: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19592' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19592' {*UND* section}

core.s:288287: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19595' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19595' {*UND* section}

core.s:288305: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19598' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19598' {*UND* section}

core.s:288414: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19617' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19617' {*UND* section}

core.s:288487: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19645' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19645' {*UND* section}

core.s:288496: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19647' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19647' {*UND* section}

core.s:288509: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19649' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19649' {*UND* section}

core.s:288536: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19658' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19658' {*UND* section}

core.s:288600: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19670' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19670' {*UND* section}

core.s:288656: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6225' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6225' {*UND* section}

core.s:288686: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19712' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19712' {*UND* section}

core.s:288693: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6260' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6260' {*UND* section}

core.s:288716: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19823' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19823' {*UND* section}

core.s:288772: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19829' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19829' {*UND* section}

core.s:288802: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19842' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19842' {*UND* section}

core.s:288926: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19873' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19873' {*UND* section}

core.s:288935: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19875' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19875' {*UND* section}

core.s:288959: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19878' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19878' {*UND* section}

core.s:288967: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19880' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19880' {*UND* section}

core.s:289082: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19913' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19913' {*UND* section}

core.s:289091: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19915' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19915' {*UND* section}

core.s:289104: Error: can't resolve `.LBE19917' {*UND* section} - `.LBB19917' {*UND* section}

core.s:289195: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6237' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6237' {*UND* section}

core.s:289234: Error: can't resolve `.LBE20340' {*UND* section} - `.LBB20340' {*UND* section}

core.s:289341: Error: can't resolve `.LBE20353' {*UND* section} - `.LBB20353' {*UND* section}

core.s:289376: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6239' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6239' {*UND* section}

core.s:289415: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6246' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6246' {*UND* section}

core.s:289454: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6761' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6761' {*UND* section}

core.s:289504: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23467' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23467' {*UND* section}

core.s:289551: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23482' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23482' {*UND* section}

core.s:289564: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23484' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23484' {*UND* section}

core.s:289577: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23486' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23486' {*UND* section}

core.s:289633: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23495' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23495' {*UND* section}

core.s:289646: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23497' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23497' {*UND* section}

core.s:289659: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23499' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23499' {*UND* section}

core.s:289787: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23515' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23515' {*UND* section}

core.s:289796: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23517' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23517' {*UND* section}

core.s:289809: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23519' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23519' {*UND* section}

core.s:289836: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23528' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23528' {*UND* section}

core.s:289900: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23540' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23540' {*UND* section}

core.s:289979: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23556' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23556' {*UND* section}

core.s:290048: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23565' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23565' {*UND* section}

core.s:290070: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23568' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23568' {*UND* section}

core.s:290088: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23571' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23571' {*UND* section}

core.s:290197: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23590' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23590' {*UND* section}

core.s:290347: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23685' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23685' {*UND* section}

core.s:290356: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23687' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23687' {*UND* section}

core.s:290369: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23689' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23689' {*UND* section}

core.s:290446: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23714' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23714' {*UND* section}

core.s:290525: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23730' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23730' {*UND* section}

core.s:290730: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23794' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23794' {*UND* section}

core.s:290735: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23802' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23802' {*UND* section}

core.s:290739: Error: can't resolve `.LBE23804' {*UND* section} - `.LBB23804' {*UND* section}

core.s:290820: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6274' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6274' {*UND* section}

core.s:290853: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6267' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6267' {*UND* section}

core.s:290886: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6277' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6277' {*UND* section}

core.s:290967: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26286' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26286' {*UND* section}

core.s:290999: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26291' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26291' {*UND* section}

core.s:291052: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26299' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26299' {*UND* section}

core.s:291065: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26302' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26302' {*UND* section}

core.s:291145: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26320' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26320' {*UND* section}

core.s:291195: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26327' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26327' {*UND* section}

core.s:291208: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26330' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26330' {*UND* section}

core.s:291238: Error: can't resolve `.LBE26336' {*UND* section} - `.LBB26336' {*UND* section}

core.s:440125: Error: can't resolve `.text.unlikely' {.text.unlikely section} - `.Ltext_cold0' {*UND* section}

core.s:440127: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6319' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6319' {*UND* section}

core.s:440129: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6561' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6561' {*UND* section}

core.s:440131: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6281' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6281' {*UND* section}

core.s:440133: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6516' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6516' {*UND* section}

core.s:440135: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6796' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6796' {*UND* section}

core.s:440137: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6336' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6336' {*UND* section}

core.s:440139: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6340' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6340' {*UND* section}

core.s:440141: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6512' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6512' {*UND* section}

core.s:440143: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6517' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6517' {*UND* section}

core.s:440145: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6343' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6343' {*UND* section}

core.s:440147: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6344' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6344' {*UND* section}

core.s:440149: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6508' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6508' {*UND* section}

core.s:440151: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6345' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6345' {*UND* section}

core.s:440153: Error: can't resolve `.LFE6513' {*UND* section} - `.LFB6513' {*UND* section}

core.s: Error: .size expression for sched_fork does not evaluate to a constant

make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:288: kernel/sched/core.o] Error 1

make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

If I remove `-save-temps` from `KBUILD_CFLAGS` and I can successfully build the kernel image, my source code is downloaded from https://www.kernel.org/ with version `linux-5.17-2`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding `KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -save-temps=obj`  to the Makefile in the root directory.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with GCC (Debian 11.3.0-11) 11.3.0 and it still fails. It also fails with `make KCFLAGS="-save-temps -P"`. The failure is quite different from yours but still, the configuration builds successfully without the additional GCC options. Have you got any clue about the main issue ever since?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I remember I run it on my ubuntu computer...